# Installing latest pgfplots for TexMaker on Mac OS

Tags: pgfplots, texmaker, mac

A basic question: I am struggling to figure out how to install the latest version of pgfplots for TexMaker 5.0.3 on my mac. I presume I need to input something into the terminal? Can anyone help?

I have downloaded the package from https://ctan.org/pkg/pgfplots?lang=en

Thanks!

Comment: TeXmaker is a front end for a TeX Distribution. What TeX Distribution are you using? E.g., did you install MacTeX (which installs TeX Live) or some other distribution?

Comment: Hi Herb, MacTex

Comment: then use TeX Live Utility and update packages. It’s in /Applications/TeX.